# Using Spring WebFlux in Vaadin

Tags: java, spring-boot, vaadin

I'm new in java ecosystem. I have a question related to Vaading and Spring Boot. It is possible to use the WebFlux Api with Vaading? Has it sense?

Comment: Are you asking, whether you can run WebFlux and Vaadin in one container or whether you can consume a WebFlux API from a Vaadin application?

Comment: I think the only option which may work with vaadin is reactive client. However its necessary to use it with @Push configuration for async UI updates. Check this:https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/advanced/tutorial-push-access.html